# Random array Android

Tags: java, android, array, random

Tengo un array en String y quiero extraer de él varios valores y mostrarlos en un textview cuando apriete un botón pero no se como sacar varios datos del array. Aqui es lo que tengo

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Random r = new Random();
        final String[] elementos = {"R","L","F","B","D","U","R'","L'","F'","B'","D'","U'","R2","L2","F2","B2","U2","D2"};
        final TextView txtScram = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtScram);

        Button btnObtener = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnObtener);
        btnObtener.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               String ranEle = elementos[r.nextInt(elementos.length)];
               txtScram.setText(ranEle);

             }


            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Tambien podrias utilizar StringBuilder y asi poder recorrer el arreglo

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < path_On.size(); i++) {
                stringBuilder.append(path_On.get(i));
            }
            String newPath = stringBuilder.toString();
```

y asignar newPath al textview

//Te agrego el siguiente ejemplo con la clase ramdom

Claro, compañero mira, puedes declarar la clase Random, como el siguiente ejemplo que te anexo dos ejemplos para que puedas guiarte un poco mejor, saludos.

```
import java.util.Random;
    public class RandomSelect {

        public static void main (String [] args) {

             String [] array = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
             Random random = new Random();

             int select = random.nextInt(array.length); 

             System.out.println("Random: " + array[select]); 
        }
    }

    Usando charAt:

    import java.util.Random;
    public class RandomSelect {

        public static void main (String [] args) {

             String text = "Hello World";
             Random random = new Random();

             int select = random.nextInt(text.length()); 

             System.out.println("Random char selected: " + text.charAt(select)); 
        }
    }
```

Tambien podrias utilizar chatAt te anexo un ejemplo saludos

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

            String value = "cat";

            for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
                char c = value.charAt(i);
                System.out.println(c);
            }
        }
```

Comment: el codigo funciona pero me imprime todo el arreglo en textview y lo que quiero conseguir es que me entrege los elementos de forma random

Comment: compañero actualice la repuesta con dos ejemplos, para que puedas guiarte mejor saludos

Comment: No agregues más de una respuesta, edita la que tienes para que sea aún mejor, revisar [answer], saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Yo agregaría un método que me entregue la cantidad de valores aleatorios que deseo del array:

```
private String getRandomValues(String[] valores, int cantidad){
    String res = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < cantidad; i++){
        res += valores[new Random().nextInt(valores.length)] + " ";
    }
    return res;
}
```

y dentro de `onClick()` lo llamo, especificando cuantos valores deseo:

```
   @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          String ranEle = getRandomValues(elementos, 5); //5 elementos aleatorios del array.  
          txtScram.setText(ranEle);
      }
```

---

Revisa esta [**demo online**](https://ideone.com/NHwx62) para probar el funcionamiento del método sugerido.

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar un for para correr varias veces tu codigo que saca los elementos

en el siguiente solo cambia `numElOut` por el numero de elementos que deseas sacar

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
           String outTxt="";
           int numElOut=12;
           for(int i=0;i<numElOut;i++)
               outTxt += elementos[r.nextInt(elementos.length)];            
           txtScram.setText(outTxt);
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

El limite de los elementos que quieres obtener de tu arreglo esta definido por ti o por el usuario? Viendo tu codigo todo funciona bien salgo que sacas solo 1 cuando en realidad quieres 1 o más. Editaria esto de tu codigo

```
Button btnObtener = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnObtener);
btnObtener.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(",");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            String ranEle = elementos[r.nextInt(elementos.length)];
            joiner.add(ranEle);
        }
        txtScram.setText(joiner.toString());
    }
}
});
```

Utilice `StringJoiner` para hacer un separador de cada palabra o elemento de tu arreglo para mostrarlo de mejor forma en el `TextView`. En mi ejemplo puedes obtener 3 elementos.